# Firestore_core initialization error, nothing wokrs

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having this issue, where this error appears:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
Restarted application in 1,035ms.
E/flutter ( 6967): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
E/flutter ( 6967): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967): #1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:353:35)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967): #2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31:23)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967): #4      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40:31)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967): #5      main (package:firebase_test/main.dart:20:3)
E/flutter ( 6967): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6967):
```

I am initializing firebase the standard way:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

This error occured suddenly when I changed picture for icon and splashscreen in `pubspec.yaml` file. Since then I reupploaded the same picture without success. Might be something with the new release of `flutter_core` 1.19.0
I have tried now everything I could find but nothing worked. From dummy restart of the application, android studio and emulator, to changing in buil.gradle this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
```

also tried changing `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` to `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`. My `flutter doctor` shows 0 issues and `flutter doctor -v` also did not find a thing. Really hopeless here, some ideas?

Comment: i am using firebase_core: ^1.17.1 version and it is working fine, can please try with 1.17.1 version?

Comment: I am unable to install any other version than the 1.19.0, or do you know how?

Comment: Sorry, already figured, you were right, the older version works

Comment: Looks like the problem is currently in the 1.19.0 version

Comment: @BillyKid yay, downgrading to 1.18.0 solved the problem for me, thanks you, can you write this as an answer to your own question? I'll upvote you then :)

Comment: @BillyKid   glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am using firebase_core: ^1.17.1 version and it is working fine, can please you try with 1.17.1 version?

Looks like there is some issue with new firebase version